# Is there an automatic way to detect when a html element (tag) is on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Imagine you want to optimize the resource loading process on a web page made of a lot of carrousels-like view, and long scrollable contents rich on images anda media resources.

I am implementing a Netflix-like gallery using angular (AngularJs, not Angular 2). I have my custom directive (in angular you should use the directive method to declare custom elements, and properties), it works fine, but now I want to use a technic similar to virtual repeaters en angular material or views adapters on Android.

I could detect what I have on screen using code to calculate position and elements, but I would really like a more direct approach. Like an event listener or some thing. Some thing I can use en a general way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres no way to do that with listener. All You can do is to use
[Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

It is going to return You distance to top, bottom, left and right of Your viewport (viewport is what user actually sees).
It is worth to mention that You can use it just on elements which are already in DOM, also - unfortunately it affects performance.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid for the performance loss. I will check the boundaries, on the scrolling callback.

Comment: Well thats not the best idea TBH. You shouldn't execute any code which could affect performance in response to scroll event. Safari (Im not sure about the last version tho) is not even going to fire those scripts untill scroll animation ends.
But if You really do not have any other options (and Your probably don't), than You should at least debounce these actions.
https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function